# jQuery Tab select tab not show text in editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, codemirror

[image]I have a jQuery tab and I have Code Mirror text editor in the tab. on page load I check out some condition:

```
    if (condition){
                $('#editors').tabs("disable",0);
                $('#editors').tabs('select', 1);
                    myCodeMirror.refresh();
    }
```

based on condition I disable one of the tag and show the next tab. It's showing tab1 correctly however the text in text editor is not visible unless I re-size browser window or start editing text editor as you can observe in image1.1
I have tried refreshing my code editor.
I thing there is something wrong with the tab select.

Comment: did you try initializing codemirror after tabs initialized? Create a demo in jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

If CodeMirror is initialized in a hidden state, it can't build up its display. You'll have to call its `refresh()` method after you un-hide it for the first time.